# How to say "away from"?

Tags: vocabulario

How would I say `away from` as in:

> There was a movement away from this trend

I used "de" but it sounds like a movement of the trend rather than away from it.

Comment: Which entry here you didn't fully agree with? http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=away%20from

Comment: Maybe you could use "alejado"

Comment: Could you give us some context for this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the sentence. In general, I would say that `away from` could be translated as something like `alejarse` (which is a verb), `alejamiento` or `estar lejos`. So that sentence would be: `Hubo un alejamiento de esta tendencia`.

Other examples would be:

`Stay away from me!` --> `Aléjate de mí`

`We are not away from home` --> `No estamos lejos de casa`

Comment: Estás seguro que esa es la traducción  de la pregunta? Yo creo que la traducción más exacta sería *Hubo un movimiento fuera de esta tendencia.* , que en mi región (Perú) sería más común dicho así: *Hubo un movimiento fuera de serie.* Creo que la traducción es más contextual que literal, algo que creo que google translate no hace

Comment: La verdad es que no tenía (ni tengo) muy claro el sentido u objetivo de la frase. Yo lo entendí más en el sentido de que se empezó a crear otra tendencia que se alejaba de la inicial. Preguntaré por si acaso. Gracias ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use

"Hubo un movimiento apartado/alejado de esta tendencia"

For this sentence in particular "alejado" and "apartado" (at least for me) mean the same.

Answer (score 0):

Playing off of makeMonday's answer, I think `lejos de` would work as well. For example:

> Los lobos se cambiaron lejos del cochino. - The wolves moved away from the pig.

Please keep in mind, though, that my knowledge of the Spanish language is not completely extensive, and a better word could work.

Comment: "Los lobos se **alejaron** del cerdo/cochino". Or even "se mudaron lejos", but no one would use "cambiaron lejos" (don't force the use of _move_ in the translation).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Again, I wasn't sure if something better would work.

Comment: Sorry, if I was too rude when pointing at it I apologize. Feel welcome to the site and please, don't hesitate to keep participating. There are a lot of people here looking forward to helping you improve your Spanish.

Comment: Oh no, I understand. I'll fully admit that I don't know everything, but I am willing to help others when I can. That, and I know that I can learn from this site myself - that's actually why I created an account in the first place.